# Find multiple occurences of string in a text file using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large *text file* which is contains the text `_ _Z_1_:_` followed by data such as:

```
_ _Z_1_:_0_1_3_4_2                      

 Fixed Totaliser Period 1 Reset Report  

 NET sales          57        £202.05   

 CASH in Drawer     55        £172.35   
 CREDIT in Drawer   2         £29.70    
 TOTAL in Drawer    57        £202.05
```

There are two occurrences of the `_ _Z_1_:_` text in each file. 
I am trying to get the macro to find the `_ _Z_1_:_` and then lift the cash amount (in the above case **£172.35**) and credit etc.

I have tried using a code to allow me to specify the text file and then used the `InStr` function but it will only identify the first occurrence. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you've tried. Edit your question, don't add it in comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811.aspx) will return the position of the first occurence. Use that position to start the search for the second.

```
dim bffr as string, p as long
bffr = (◄ assign the text here)
p = instr(p + 1, bffr, "_ _Z_1_:_", vbtextconpare)
do while cbool(p)

  '_ _Z_1_:_ was found; process it based upon the starting position p

  'see if there are other occurrences of _ _Z_1_:_
  p = instr(p + 1, bffr, "_ _Z_1_:_", vbtextconpare)
loop
```

By continually advancing the search by starting one character ahead of the last position it was found you will walk through the buffer holding the text and pick up a new p for each occurrence. When it can no longer be found, InStr returns zero to p.